# how to set cron job every 2 hours in difference time? [cron version ^1.1.0]

Tags: node.js, cron

i want to set the cron job every 2 hours in difference time

lets say current time is 1 PM so the example what i want is :

1st cron job run hours : 1 PM , 3 PM , 5 PM , 7 PM , etc

2nd cron job run hours : 2 PM , 4 PM , 6 PM , 8 PM , etc

```
new CronJob('0 0 */2 * * *', function() {
    ...
}, null, true);
```

how can i modify this cronjob ? Thanks

Comment: why does this need to be a node script?

Comment: You can run cron every hour and put if condition on if hour is even then run this else run second command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*/2` will give you even numbers and is the same as `0/2`. `1/2` will give you uneven numbers. So this should work:

```
new CronJob('0 0 1/2 * * *', function() {
    // 1st cron job
}, null, true);
new CronJob('0 0 0/2 * * *', function() {
    // 2nd cron job
}, null, true);
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not working 
i found another way from your explanation


        `new CronJob('0 0 0-23/2 * * *', function() {
             // 1st cron job
         }, null, true);

         new CronJob('0 0 1-23/2 * * *', function() {
            // 2nd cron job
        }, null, true);`

Comment: My syntax works with vanilla cron. I guess the cron lib you're using doesn't support full cron compatibility. How about you update your question to include the name of the cron library you're using, and I'll update my answer so this will be more useful to future readers?